# Images not appearing in Applet on the web

Tags: java

I am currently building a website using Middleman, and I would like to incorporate some Applets. So far I have successfully added my applet to the my website, however, the applet will not show any of the images used. Other than that, the applet works as intended. My Java code is as follows (Please forgive me that the code is in a snipet, the code spacing wouldn't format correctly).

```js
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Dodger extends java.applet.Applet
implements Runnable {
 
 Thread runner;
 Image[] BadGuys=new Image[10];  //Array for amount of bad guys to draw
 int[] BadGuysSize= new int[10]; //Array for the particular size of each bad guy
 Image EnemyBig;  //Image for the Big enemy
 Image EnemyMedium;  //Image for the Medium
 Image EnemySmall; //Image for the Small
 Image User;   //Image of user
 int[] YPos=new int[10];  //Y position used for each bad guy
 int[] XPosMid=new int[10];
 int[] XPos=new int[10];  //X position used for each bad guy
 int[] YPosMid=new int[10];
 int[] speed=new int[10];
 int xCoordMouse;  //X Coordinate of the mouse
 int yCoordMouse;  //Y coordinate of the mouse
 boolean LostGame=false; //Boolean for when the game ends
 int Score=0;  //Variable for score
 int Speed=15;  //Variable for speed
 
 public void init() {
  setSize(375, 600);
  EnemyBig = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"EnemyBig.jpg");   //Import the character's images
  EnemyMedium = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"EnemyMedium.jpg");
  EnemySmall = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"EnemySmall.jpg");
  User = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"User.jpg");
  
  
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
   BadGuys[i]=EnemySmall;  //for loop for creating small enemies
   YPosMid[i]= (YPos[i]+16);
   XPosMid[i]= (XPos[i]+16);
  }
  
  for(int i=3; i<6; i++){  //for loop for the medium
   BadGuys[i]=EnemyMedium;
   YPosMid[i]= (YPos[i]+21);
   XPosMid[i]= (XPos[i]+21);
  }
  
  for(int i=6; i<10; i++){ //and the Big ones
   BadGuys[i]=EnemyBig;
   YPosMid[i]= (YPos[i]+30);
   XPosMid[i]= (XPos[i]+30);
  }
  
  for(int i=0; i<BadGuys.length; i++){    //Sets up the relative position of the enemies
   XPos[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*getWidth()));
   YPos[i] = (-(int)(Math.random()*200));
  }
  
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   speed[i]=(int)(Math.random()*3+1);
 }
 
  

  public void start()
  {
    if (runner == null)
    {
      runner = new Thread(this);
      runner.start();
    }
  }

  public void stop()
  {
    if (runner != null)
    {
     runner.stop();
      runner = null;
    }
  }

  public void run()
  {
    while(!LostGame)
    {
      repaint();
      
      //update X and Y position of Bad Guys
      for(int i=0;i<YPos.length;i++){
       YPos[i]+=speed[i];      
      if (YPos[i] > getHeight()){
       YPos[i] = (-(int)(Math.random()*200));
       XPos[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*getWidth()-10));
       Score++;
      
      }   
   }
   
     for(int i=0; i<3; i++){  //small ones
   YPosMid[i]= (YPos[i]+16);
   XPosMid[i]= (XPos[i]+16);
  }
  
  for(int i=3; i<6; i++){  //for loop for the medium
   YPosMid[i]= (YPos[i]+21);
   XPosMid[i]= (XPos[i]+21);
  }
  
  for(int i=6; i<10; i++){ //and the Big ones
   YPosMid[i]= (YPos[i]+30);
   XPosMid[i]= (XPos[i]+30);
  }
     
   
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++){   //Small Enemy
   if(Math.abs((xCoordMouse+20)-XPosMid[i])<=36&&Math.abs((yCoordMouse+20)-YPosMid[i])<=36)
    LostGame=true;  
  }
  
   for(int i=3; i<6; i++){   //Medium Enemy
   if(Math.abs((xCoordMouse+20)-XPosMid[i])<=41&&Math.abs((yCoordMouse+20)-YPosMid[i])<=41)
    LostGame=true;
  }
  
   for(int i=6; i<10; i++){  //Large Enemy
   if(Math.abs((xCoordMouse+20)-XPosMid[i])<=50&&Math.abs((yCoordMouse+20)-YPosMid[i])<=50)
    LostGame=true;
  } 
  
      
  
      try {Thread.sleep(Speed);}
      catch(InterruptedException e) { }
    }
  }
  
    public boolean mouseMove(Event e, int x, int y)  //keeps track of the position of the mouse and puts the user image in the ceneter of the cursor
 {
  
  xCoordMouse = x-20;
  yCoordMouse = y-20;
  return true;
 }

 public void paint(Graphics g) {
  
  
  
  for(int i=0;i<BadGuys.length;i++){
   g.drawImage(BadGuys[i],XPos[i], YPos[i], this);   //draws the bad guys
  }
  
  g.drawImage(User,xCoordMouse,yCoordMouse,this);    //draws the user
  
  g.drawString("Score: "+Score,10,20);      //draws the score
  
  Font myFont = new Font("comic sans", Font.BOLD, 18); //sets up the font
  g.setFont(myFont);
   
  if(LostGame){
  g.drawString("You Lost!",((getWidth()/2)-35),(getHeight()/2));  //sets up the result for when the user finally loses
  g.drawString("Final Score: "+Score,((getWidth()/2)-35),((getHeight()/2)+20));
  }
 }
}
```

The file structure currently for my the webpage looks like this:
Games -> dodger -> Dodger -> In here includes the .class, .jar, and all the images.

My index.html then looks like this: `<applet codebase="Dodger" archive="Dodger.jar" code="Dodger.class" width="375" height="600">The browser you are using does not support Java Applets.</applet>`

Comment: Applets are (for all intents and purposes) dead. The browsers block the plug-in.

Comment: I don't disagree, I wouldn't use them if I didn't have to, however this is for my Computer Science Final.

Comment: [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).